What are the best practices for determining appropriate input fields for a form by gathering the context only from the backend developer?
I'm currently tasked with designing a user form for a data solution product, but facing a bit of challenges. I do have a basic knowledge of the products' goals but haven't been provided with clear and specific details about what input fields are necessary for the users to fill out. Right now, I only have the opportunity to gather insights from the backend developer who has the system design ready.
I'm assuming JSON format would be helpful but want to know if any strategies can be followed.
I appreciate any advice or, real-life examples from your experiences that could guide me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

If the backend has an API (REST, GraphQL etc.) it likely has generated documentation that shows the type of each field with a description (containing the requirements and limitations) and an example. Ask the backend developer for the URL because it is easier to read than a JSON document.

If the dev has developed the API, he/she has defined requirements informed by business requirements. So follow what the API needs. Ask the dev for the documentation. If no documentation exists, then you will have to interview the dev and write it out. Make sure the dev has developed it based on some sort of requirement and not in silo. A product manager would also have more contextual knowledge about what is needed.

You need to distinguish here: One side is the data transmission in a JSON format or something similar. The other side is how to display this data. In a UI that only needs to show things, this is easily done with a multiline text field or some labels if you want to design things. If there is also edit functionality involved, you have these two sides again. The UI side is complex, would need another question for it.

The backend developer can provide complete database table details. Get all the record details from the raw DB table which will give you a good idea of what kind of data you need to gather. Then you can sort and group them as however it makes sense, even use Card Sorting if necessary. Since you know the goal of the product, you should be able to put the fields in the order of their priority to whatever extent. Put all those fields in order and create a mockup form. Then review those with a few users. Reviews with the primary persona, usage of that database in other applications (dependency check) and business goals of the product will let you know what the mandatory and priority fields are. This exercise should get you to MVP stage.
